# Calling a paint function from CDialog::OnPaint

Tags: winapi, mfc

Well I want a pretty simple thing, but a bit of confused.

```
    void CAppDlg::OnPaint()
    {
      CPaintDC dc(this);
      CDC pdc;
      pdc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
      CBitmap *oldBmp = pdc.SelectObject(&m_BmpImg[0]);
      dc.BitBlt(0, 0, m_SizBmpImg[0].cx, m_SizBmpImg[0].cy, &pdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
      dc.SelectObject(&oldBmp);
    }
```

In the above code snippet I would like to put last 3 lines to a separate function. Now I cannot pass CPaintDC as a function parameter, I need to convert it to CDC or CMemDC. And also how do I pass this pdc (CDC pdc) or shall I create a new one inside my function.

A sample with bit of explanation would be off a great help.

Comment: You can pass anything as a parameter by reference or pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
void CAppDlg::OnPaint()
{
  CPaintDC dc(this);
  CDC pdc;
  pdc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

  YourSeparateFUnction(dc, pdc);
}

void  CAppDlg::YourSeparateFUnction(CPaintDC & dc, CDC & pdc)
{
  CBitmap *oldBmp = pdc.SelectObject(&m_BmpImg[0]);
  dc.BitBlt(0, 0, m_SizBmpImg[0].cx, m_SizBmpImg[0].cy, &pdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  dc.SelectObject(&oldBmp);
}
```

Comment: void CAppDlg::PaintSeperated(CDC *pDC, CDC *pDcCompatible) - 
As I believe CPaintDC is only available inside OnPaint.

Comment: Are you calling `PaintSeperated` from other functions than `OnPaint` ?

Comment: @hypheni: `CPaintDC` does not represent a special device context. The only difference between `CPaintDC` and `CDC` is, that the former calls `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` in the c'tor and d'tor, respectively, to properly validate the screen area. Passing a `CPaintDC` by reference is not a problem, although you could (or should) pass the generic base class by reference instead: `CDC&`.